# How to add age to ageList =[12,13,23]

Tags: list, groovy

may be too simple groovy question but....please help

i have a list like this:

```
def ageList =[12,13,23]
```

i want to get this:

```
def newAgeList =[age:12,age:13,age:23]
```

could some one help me out?

thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is possible since you want to use the same map key 'age' for three different values. You'll end up overwriting the existing value with a new value.

Comment: thanks!  how about using List.add() to create a new list?  

def rawLines = [1,2,3]
 
def lines = []  
rawLines.each { 
        lines.add("good") 
} 

I tried above, not working..

I'm just learning groovy....

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you?

```
def newAgeList = ageList.inject([:]) { map, item -> if (!map['age']) map['age'] = []; map['age'] << item; map }
```

his would result in:  `['age':[12, 13, 23]]`

Otherwise, you can get the literal value as something like:

```
def newAgeList = ageList.collect { "age:$it" }
```

his would result in:  `['age:12', 'age:13', 'age:23']`

A third option:

```
def newAgeList = ageList.collect { ['age':it] }
```

This would result in: `[['age':12], ['age':13], ['age':23]]`

Unfortunately, you can't do this as a map like you showed above as map keys must be unique.

Really it all depends on what you are trying to do with the result.